# Run a single Junit Test in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, junit, junit4

I am new in  IntelliJ IDEA and I want to execute a single Junit test as I do in Eclipse but I haven't seen this option

[image]

Comment: If you look at your code, you should see a little green arrow to the left of the method

Comment: Or you can right click the method name and select `run myMethodName()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Intellij runs the unit test in context of your selection!

When you place the cursor on the class name, it will *run* the whole class. If you select a method name, only that method gets executed (upon turning to the menu or context menu).

You can also select a package in the project view and get to corresponding behavior.

Comment: could you please tell me how to debug a particular junit test in Intellij. Earlier i used eclipse but I am unable to do so in intelij

Comment: You select the method, either in the editor or the structure view, right click and select "debug". Also note that intellij has excellent help pages explaining such things.

Answer (score 1):

Open the class where the tests are located and check the part where inteliJ shows the the number of lines, at the beginning of each test method there is a green icon (looks like a play button) just hit that icon and the specific test method will be executed.

Comment: Sadly, this is broken in IntelliJ 2019.3.3 (at least for Kotlin). Until you run *all* the tests in the test suite, you cannot run an individual test.

Comment: Agree with John Kaster. You cannot run an individual test whether it is Java or Kotlin.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my issue by Uncheck the "Delegate IDE build/run actions to Maven".
I think this works for IntelliJ version higher( in my case is 2023.1.1)
Go to Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Maven -> Runner and Uncheck the "Delegate IDE build/run actions to Maven".

Hope it is useful!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBltJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please place caret inside test method you want to launch and using right click context menu launch single test.